# Xamarin binding .aar Google Vr View library

Tags: c#, android, maven, xamarin, binding

I'm new in this blog, but I suffered a question to ask. Recently, I was assigned a task to develop a viewer for 360 degree video for mobile devices in Xamarin environment and to do that I want to use the library Of Google VR. My problem is that in carrying out the binding operation of .aar package methods are not returned all those required in the documentation because of missing dependencies you can pull out of its .pom file. or tried everything: download all the necessary Nuget packages, use Xamarin components with metadata appropriate to achieve the desired result, the Gradle building to get a better result but nothing, other even libraries. So I ask you, in addition to sending the possible mistakes I've seen, if anyone has had the same problem and found a way to solve it, like a tutorial also. Thanks who gives me a good answer.

```
JARTOXML : Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning : ignoring option UseSplitVerifier; support was removed in 8.0
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8900: Type com.google.android.exoplayer2.metadata.Metadata: FxDG naming violation: Type name 'Metadata' matches namespace part 'Metadata'.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8D00: More than 16 parameters were found, which goes beyond the maximum number of parameters. (in method CreateAudioSampleFormat in managed type Com.Google.Android.Exoplayer2.Format)
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8900: Type com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.chunk.Chunk: FxDG naming violation: Type name 'Chunk' matches namespace part 'Chunk'.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method CreateFromXml in managed type Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method CreateFromXml in managed type Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method ParseBundleExtras in managed type Android.Content.Res.Resources.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method CreateFromXml in managed type Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method CreateFromXml in managed type Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method CreateFromXmlInner in managed type Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method CreateFromXmlInner in managed type Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method Inflate in managed type Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method Inflate in managed type Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method ParseIntent in managed type Android.Content.Intent.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method ReadFromXml in managed type Android.Content.IntentFilter.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8C00: For type Com.Google.Android.Exoplayer2.Drm.StreamingDrmSessionManager.MediaDrmEventListener, base interface com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.ExoMediaDrm.OnEventListener<T> is invalid.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8801: Invalid parameter type com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.ExoMediaDrm<? extends T> in method OnEvent in managed type Com.Google.Android.Exoplayer2.Drm.StreamingDrmSessionManager.MediaDrmEventListener.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8900: Type com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util: FxDG naming violation: Type name 'Util' matches namespace part 'Util'.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method Inflate in managed type Android.Views.LayoutInflater.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8800: Unknown parameter type System.Xml.XmlReader in method Inflate in managed type Android.Views.LayoutInflater.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8900: Type com.google.android.exoplayer2.metadata.Metadata: FxDG naming violation: Type name 'Metadata' matches namespace part 'Metadata'.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8900: Type com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.chunk.Chunk: FxDG naming violation: Type name 'Chunk' matches namespace part 'Chunk'.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8C00: For type Com.Google.Android.Exoplayer2.Drm.StreamingDrmSessionManager.MediaDrmEventListener, base interface com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.ExoMediaDrm.OnEventListener<T> is invalid.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8C00: For type Com.Google.Android.Exoplayer2.Source.Hls.HlsMediaPeriod, base interface com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.HlsSampleStreamWrapper.Callback is invalid.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8900: Type com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util: FxDG naming violation: Type name 'Util' matches namespace part 'Util'.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8501: empty event name in Com.Google.Android.Exoplayer2.IExoPlayerEventListener.AddListener.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8401: Skipping Com.Google.Android.Exoplayer2.Period.DurationUs, due to a duplicate field, method or nested type name.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8401: Skipping Com.Google.Android.Exoplayer2.Window.DefaultPositionUs, due to a duplicate field, method or nested type name.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8401: Skipping Com.Google.Android.Exoplayer2.Window.DurationUs, due to a duplicate field, method or nested type name.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8401: Skipping Com.Google.Android.Exoplayer2.Window.PositionInFirstPeriodUs, due to a duplicate field, method or nested type name.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8501: empty event name in Com.Google.Android.Exoplayer2.Source.Hls.Playlist.HlsPlaylistTracker.IPlaylistEventListener.AddListener.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8401: Skipping Com.Google.Android.Exoplayer2.Source.Smoothstreaming.Manifest.SsManifest.ProtectionElement, due to a duplicate field, method or nested type name.
1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : warning BG8401: Skipping Com.Google.Android.Exoplayer2.Trackselection.BaseTrackSelection.Length, due to a duplicate field, method or nested type name.
```